# errors installing npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to node.js and trying to install some packages like express and jade but its getting me frustrated, every time I am encountering different kind of errors some of which are

```
         ENOENT
         EADDRINFO
         Could not load package.json
```

I have also googled it but nothing helped me, I am on a wi-fi network provided by our college(cyberoam) and tor-deamon is installed on my linux machine. Any good tutorials to install npm packages properly will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? `npm install packagename`?

Comment: npm install --registry http://registry.npms.org/express

Comment: That's just wrong. The npmjs.org is the default registry. Just do `npm install express`. Use registry only if you have your own custom npm server running somewhere.
P.S.: You maybe messed up your npm installation.

Comment: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Comment: npm ERR! registry error parsing json :(

Comment: That's because you screwed up the registry. Google around for restoring or reinstall node.js + npm.

Comment: its showing up same error but this time due the tor running on my machine
 <head>
 <title>Tor is not an HTTP Proxy</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Tor is not an HTTP Proxy</h1>
 <p>
 It appears you have configured your web browser to use Tor as an HTTP proxy.
This is not correct: Tor is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy.
Please configure your client accordingly.
</p>

npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>

Comment: I googled npm proxy. Maybe this could help: http://www.planetholt.com/2012/03/15/using-npm-proxy/2616

Comment: I tried for everything but nothing helped me, I uninstalled tor, cloned express and npm install ./express and also went with the following answer but I am getting an error of ECONNREFUSED ,please help!

Comment: You need a clean install with the correct registry. After that you should set a proxy like you do in your browser or any other application that requires an internet connection.

Comment: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, ECONNRESET
:( is there any way so that I can install express manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing following commands on your command prompt, by replacing proxy address:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```